# Set variable and pass to function or re-set variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, modular

Which is best? Set a variable and pass it into the call, or set the var again every time. I want `self = this` (i.e. the Slider obj) for consistency.

**EDIT** for answers: I know I can use `this` but I work with other team members and have agreed for consistency to use `self` when referencing the object at all times.

So is this better:

```
Slider = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this,
        foo = $('.someElement');

        self.bindEvent(self);
    },

    bindEvent: function(self) {
        self.foo.on('click', self.wasClicked(self));
    },

    wasClicked: function(e, self) {
        e.doSomething();
        self.done();
    }
};
```

Or this:

```
Slider = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this,
        foo = $('.someElement');

        self.bindEvent();
    },

    bindEvent: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.foo.on('click', self.wasClicked);
    },

    wasClicked: function(e) {
        var self = Slider;
        e.doSomething();
        self.done();
    }
};
```

Comment: You only need `self` in `wasClicked`, in the other cases use `this`. Also, you can't call `Slider.init()` like that in an object. I believe you want a constructor function instead.

Comment: I know I can use `this` but I work with other team members and have agreed for consistency to use self when referencing the object at all times. Also I the init call was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is more reusable if you utilize an argument for your binding target, as per your first example. For instance:

```
bindEvent: function(target) {
    target.onclick = function() { alert(target + " was clicked"); };
}
```

`bindEvent()` can now be called by other functions, and target something other than `self`. While in your current Slider object it only needs to be called by `init()`, in the future you may end up adding functionality to Slider that would be benefit from the added reusability of this function. At that point in time you can avoid rewriting the function, or worse yet creating an essentially duplicate function for the new usecase.

In situations where `self` is not the target, merely a reference to the parent, either example is fine. If your function already has a lengthy list of arguments it accepts, setting `self` inside the function instead of passing it as an argument is often a good idea. Lots of arguments make it harder to understand, refactor, and test, code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `self` in `wasClicked`, in the other cases use `this`:

```
Slider = {

    init: function() {
        foo = $('.someElement');
        this.bindEvent();
    },

    bindEvent: function() {
        this.foo.on('click', this.wasClicked);
    },

    wasClicked: function(e) {
        var self = Slider;
        e.doSomething;
        self.done();
    }

}

Slider.init();
```

Regarding your edit: in the first option, the event handler won't work, because you're calling it right away instead of passing a reference. You'd have to modify the method to return a function.